# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldnt find Story with 'id'="namegoeshere")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku, elasticsearch, rails-activerecord

So I've searched the forms for awhile now and so far a lot of the fixes that I have tried have led me down a rabbits hole. That being said I'm trying to look at a story I have just created, but when I go to see view it I get the error 
"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Story with 'id'="namegoeshere")".

It then points to my stories_controller for 'show'

```
  def show
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
    @responses = @story.responses.includes(:user)
    @related_stories = @story.related_stories
    if request.path != story_path(@story)
      redirect_to @story, status: 301
    end
  end
```

I am unclear what could be happening here, for I thought that

```
   @story = Story.find(params[:id])
```

would list all of the stories. Here is are my routes

```
  resources :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update] do
    resources :recommended_stories, only: [:index]
  end

  resources :stories, except: [:index] do
    resources :responses, only: [:create]
  end
```

The section in this show.html.erb file

```
 <div class="sidebar-top-stories">
   <ul>
     <% @dashboard.top_articles.each_with_index do |story, index| %>
       <li class="top-articles-list-item">
         <div class="count-button-wrapper">
           <span class="count-button"><%= index + 1 %></span>
         </div>
         <div class="top-articles-links">
           <%= link_to story.title, story, class: 'story-title' %><br/>
           <small>
             <%= react_component("PopoverLink", { user_id: story.user.id, url: user_path(story.user), children: story.username }) %>
           </small>
         </div>
       </li>
     <% end %>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

In model Story

```
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: [ :slugged, :history, :finders ]
```

This is the log for cmd Story.find_each(&:save)
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LYsr.jpg)

Some help in solving this dilemma would be appreciated thanks.

If anymore info is needed let me know.

Comment: what URL are you using to reach the story page?

Comment: The link at the point `where I go to see view` is probably incorrect. Can you post the relevant part of the view where that link is?

Comment: added the view in which I'm clicking @SteveTurczyn

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim added view file

Comment: @ChrisLewis  Did you overwrite #to_param on the Story model?

Comment: I used friendly_id, will edit question to show @AlexandreAngelim

Comment: That's weird. It should be working. try `Story.friendly.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Maybe that Story didn't get saved after you added `FriendlyId`. If you added it afterwards, start up a console and do `Story.find_each(&:save)`

Comment: ran the command and believe my error might be with Elasticsearch, because it ran through Friendly_id_slugs but returned nill once elasticsearch ran its index job. Will investigate and update. @AlexandreAngelim Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: It maybe silly, but did you restarted server after gem install?

Comment: @ChrisLewis no problem. Good luck

Comment: @MoatazZaitoun yes I restared no luck there

Comment: @MoatazZaitoun elasticsearch was not the problem as far as I can tell, if you or anyone thinks of something, post it, I'll keep working to solve the problem.

Comment: So I fixed the problem which was really weird, basically I added the friendly part as suggested by @AlexandreAngelim, removed require(:story) from story_params in the private section in stories_controller.  Finally the last but not least I had a typo in the show.html with displaying a picture. AlexandreAngelim if you want to make that the answer I'll mark it as so, seeing that everything after was on me as far as the error went.

Comment: @ChrisLewis I think you should write the answer explaining what you did and mark it as resolved. I'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error was two fold, first part the friendly id gem is what caused me to receive the ActiveError Message. The second part was that I'm using elasticsearch with my app, my users/stories where not being index. Therefore every time I went to post a story my app could not find the user/story id(aka friendly id) in which elasticsearch was trying to find the friendly id.  So I added friendly to method,

```
def show
@story = Story.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

then I manually ran elasticsearch index for each table I wanted searchable.

```
bundle run rake elasticsearch:import:model Class='User' Force=y
```

Once these two things where accomplished everything was finally running fine.

It is worth noting that I built the app on windows platform, so I might have had to do more things then necessary if I where to have built it running on apple or linux.